# Overriding Enum in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have AABlurAlertController library popup which has buttons with some color and need to change its Color which is contained in enum case. I tried to override the enum case but it throws handler error.

```
open class AABlurAlertAction: UIButton {
        fileprivate var handler: ((AABlurAlertAction) -> Void)? = nil
        fileprivate var style: AABlurActionStyle = AABlurActionStyle.default
        fileprivate var parent: AABlurAlertController? = nil

        public init(title: String?, style: AABlurActionStyle, handler: ((AABlurAlertAction) -> Void)?) {
            super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

            self.style = style
            self.handler = handler

            self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            self.setTitle(title, for: UIControlState.normal)

            switch self.style {
            case .cancel:
                self.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0.47, green:0.50, blue:0.55, alpha:1.00), for: UIControlState.normal)
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.94, blue:0.95, alpha:1.00)
                self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.74, green:0.77, blue:0.79, alpha:1.00).cgColor
                self.layer.borderWidth = 1
                self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
                self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
                self.layer.shadowRadius = 4
                self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
            case .modernCancel:
                self.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0.47, green:0.50, blue:0.56, alpha:1.00), for: UIControlState.normal)
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.94, blue:0.95, alpha:1.00)
                self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            case .modern:
                self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.28, green:0.56, blue:0.90, alpha:1.00)
                self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            default:
                self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.31, green:0.57, blue:0.87, alpha:1.00)
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.17, green:0.38, blue:0.64, alpha:1.00).cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
            }
            self.setTitleColor(self.titleColor(for: UIControlState.normal)?.withAlphaComponent(0.5), for: UIControlState.highlighted)
        }

        required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        }

        @objc fileprivate func buttonTapped(_ sender: AABlurAlertAction) {
            self.parent?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.handler?(sender)
            })
        }
    }
```

We access it the library in our code as below

```
   let vc = AABlurAlertController()
    vc.addAction(action: AABlurAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("No", comment: ""), style: AABlurActionStyle.modernCancel) { _ in
            })
```

But when I tried to override like this

```
let vc = AABlurAlertController()
vc.addAction(action: AABlurAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("No", comment: ""), style: AABlurActionStylestyle: AABlurActionStyle, handler: ((AABlurAlertAction) -> Void)?) {
            super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

            self.style = style
            self.handler = handler

            self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            self.setTitle(title, for: UIControlState.normal)

            switch self.style {

            default:
                self.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0.27, green:0.20, blue:0.26, alpha:1.00), for: UIControlState.normal)
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.23, green:0.24, blue:0.25, alpha:1.00)
            self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            }
            self.setTitleColor(self.titleColor(for: UIControlState.normal)?.withAlphaComponent(0.5), for: UIControlState.highlighted)
        })
```

I'm getting this Error

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AABlurAlertAction' with an argument list of type '(title: String, style: AABlurActionStyle
```

Comment: This is just a one file of library, edit colors or whatever you want there and use it.

Comment: Yes but i need the same color in other controller thats y

Comment: so edit library so it takes a color in initialiser

Comment: Is it possible to add a case to an **enum** with **extension** ?

Comment: It is **not** possible